# Force redirect to https by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have domain and a subdomain like example.com and blog.example.com and enabled ssl for both using wildcard on bluehost. I add following code suggested by bluehost

## Custom subdomain .htaccess SSL + WordPress

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.maindomain.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.maindomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
    # End custom subdomain .htaccess

    # Custom maindomain .htaccess WordPress
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?maindomain.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # End custom maindomain .htaccess
```

sites are running on https properly but they are accessible on http as well.

i tried following code to force redirect but its not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

also i have two htaccess file for main domain and for subdomain and above code is placed in main domain htaccess file.

am i doing something wrong or missing something to force all urls to open with https://  ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

For only domain

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

For subdomain(place .htaccess inside subdomain folder)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blog.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```